# What is the best way to display the result of this array

Tags: php, arrays, string, algorithm, if-statement

i have a multidimentionla array

```
array(
    "Airportbus"=>array(
                       "NO"=>array(
                                  "from"=>"Barcelona",
                                  "to"=>"Gerona"
                                  )
                       ),
    "flight"=>array(
                    "SK455"=>array(
                                 "from"=>"Gerona",
                                  "to"=>"Stockholm",
                                  "seat"=>"3A"
                               ),
                    "SK22"=>array(
                                "from"=>"Stockholm",
                                 "to"=>"New york",
                                 "gate"=>"Gate 22",
                                 "description"=>"Baggage wiil be transfered from your last leg",
                                 "seat"=>"7B"
                               )
                  ),
  "train"=>array(
                  "78A"=>array(
                                "from"=>"Madrid",
                                 "to"=>"Barcelona",
                                 "seat"=>"45B"
                               )
                )
           );
```

I want to print a result like this .

```
1. Take train 78A from Madrid to Barcelona. Sit in seat 45B. 
2. Take the airport bus from Barcelona to Gerona Airport. No seat assignment. 
3. From Gerona Airport, take ﬂight SK455 to Stockholm. Gate 45B, seat 3A. Baggage drop at ticket counter 344.
4. From Stockholm, take ﬂight SK22 to New York JFK. Gate 22, seat 7B. Baggage will we automatically transferred from your last leg.
```

The problems  here are

1.some arrays have more elements with different keys `"gate","description"`.
2.some additional text are print in the result , " Sit in" , "Take" .

i tried to print the result with

```
$message = "";


if(issset($result['key']))
{
  $message += " some text ".$result['key']. " some text ",
}
if(issset($result['key2']))
{
  $message += " some text ".$result['key2']. " some text ",
}
if(issset($result['key2']))
{
  $message += " some text ".$result['key2']. " some text ",
}
```

I think if is inefficient because every time new array key added i have to add more code .

**is there any better way to do in a situation like this** , please help . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: well at least start with a loop. your array doesn't match your output. How do you know the order is train-bus-flight, the array has bus-flight- train

Comment: @Dagon can you please provide me a simple  example :(

Comment: @Dagon , mm there is no order  :(

Comment: then how can you know what happens when? do i bus or train first?

Comment: @Dagon There is an algorithm for do that ;) , my only problem is print the result .  i have implementesd the algortithm

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya check out my answer as well, it might be something useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this ruff sketch gets you somewhere

```
$out='';
foreach($resut as $k=>$v){
if($k=='Airportbus'){
//process bus
}

if($k=='Train'){
//process train
foreach($v as $kk=>$vv){

$trainid=$kk;
$from=$v[$kk]['from'];
$to=$v[$kk]['to'];
$seat=$v[$kk]['seat'];
$out .='you sit in.'$seat.' from '.$from.' to '.$to.' on train: '.$trainid;                               
}
}

}
```

alternative create functions:

```
function train($data){
 foreach($data as $kk=>$vv){

    $trainid=$kk;
    $from=$v[$kk]['from'];
    $to=$v[$kk]['to'];
    $seat=$v[$kk]['seat'];
    $out .='you sit in.'$seat.' from '.$from.' to '.$to;                               
    }

return $out;

}
```

Comment: what more do you need ?

Comment: you may like to create functions one for each transport, parse the array and return the string, a little cleaner appraoach

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you need as well (at least close enough):

```
$transport_data = YOUR_DATA;

$count = 1;
foreach ($transport_data as $transport_type => $transports) {
    foreach($transports as $transport_id => $transport_details) {
        echo $count . "." . " Take " . $transport_type . " " . $transport_id . " ";
        echo "from " . $transport_details['from'] . " to " . $transport_details['to'] . ". ";

        echo "Seating is ";
        if(array_key_exists('seat', $transport_details)) { // if seat exists, display it
            echo "Seat " . $transport_details['seat'] . ". ";
        } else {
            echo "not assigned. ";
        }

        echo "Gate is ";
        if(array_key_exists('gate', $transport_details)) { // if gate exists, display it
            echo $transport_details['gate'] . ". ";
        } else {
            echo "not assigned. ";
        }

        if(array_key_exists('description', $transport_details)) { // if description exists, display it
            echo $transport_details['description'] . ". ";
        } 
        echo  "\n";
        $count = $count + 1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1. Take Airportbus NO from Barcelona to Gerona. Seating is not assigned. Gate is not assigned. 
2. Take flight SK455 from Gerona to Stockholm. Seating is Seat 3A. Gate is not assigned. 
3. Take flight SK22 from Stockholm to New york. Seating is Seat 7B. Gate is Gate 22. Baggage wiil be transfered from your last leg. 
4. Take train 78A from Madrid to Barcelona. Seating is Seat 45B. Gate is not assigned.
```

Answer (score 0):

My procedural solution without validation or comments:

```
<?php

function printDefaultTransportation($properties) {
    $type = $properties['type'];
    $from = $properties['from'];
    $to   = $properties['to'];
    $id   = isset($properties['id']) ? $properties['id'] : null;
    $seat = isset($properties['seat']) ? $properties['seat'] : null;

    echo "Take $type";
    if( $id !== null ) {
        echo " $id";
    }
    echo " from $from to $to.";
    echo isset($seat) ? " Sit in $seat." : ' No seat assignment.';
}

function printAirportTransportation($properties) {
    $id   = $properties['id'];
    $from = $properties['from'];
    $to   = $properties['to'];
    $seat = isset($properties['seat']) ? $properties['seat'] : null;
    $gate = isset($properties['gate']) ? $properties['gate'] : null;
    $description = isset($properties['description']) ? $properties['description'] : null;

    echo "From $from Airport, take flight $id to $to.";
    if( $gate !== null ) {
        echo " $gate";
        if( $seat !== null ) {
            echo ", seat $seat";
        }
        echo '.';
    } else if( $seat !== null ) {
        echo " Seat $seat.";
    }
    if( $description !== null ) {
        echo " $description.";
    }
}

function printTransportation($type, $id, $extra) {
    static $functionsTypesMap = ['train'      => 'printDefaultTransportation',
                                 'airportbus' => 'printDefaultTransportation',
                                 'flight'     => 'printAirportTransportation'];

    $properties = array_merge(['type' => $type, 'id' => $id], $extra);
    call_user_func($functionsTypesMap[$type], $properties);
}

function printTransportations(array $transportations) {
    foreach($transportations as $k => $v) {
        $transportations[strtolower($k)] = $v;
    }

    $i = 1;
    static $orderedTypes = ['train', 'airportbus', 'flight'];
    foreach($orderedTypes as $type) {
        if( !isset($transportations[$type]) ) {
            continue;
        }

        foreach($transportations[$type] as $id => $properties) {
            if( $i > 1 ) {
                echo "\n";
            }
            echo "$i. ";
            printTransportation($type,
                                (strtolower($id)==='no'? null : $id),
                                $properties);
            ++$i;
        }
    }
}

$arr = ["Airportbus" => ["NO" => ["from" => "Barcelona",
                                  "to"   => "Gerona"]],
        "flight"     => ["SK455" => ["from" => "Gerona",
                                     "to"   => "Stockholm",
                                     "seat" => "3A"],
                         "SK22"  => ["from" => "Stockholm",
                                     "to"   => "New york",
                                     "gate" => "Gate 22",
                                     "description" => "Baggage wiil be transfered from your last leg",
                                     "seat" => "7B"]],
        "train"      => ["78A" => ["from" => "Madrid",
                                   "to"   => "Barcelona",
                                   "seat" => "45B"]]
];

printTransportations($arr);
```

The output is:

```
 1. Take train 78A from Madrid to Barcelona. Sit in 45B.
 2. Take airportbus from Barcelona to Gerona. No seat assignment.
 3. From Gerona Airport, take flight SK455 to Stockholm. Seat 3A.
 4. From Stockholm Airport, take flight SK22 to New york. Gate 22, seat 7B. Baggage wiil be transfered from your last leg.
```

Comments:

- The gate is missing at "flight SK455" because the input does not have it.
- "New York" is outputted as "New york" (it's from the array value).
- I think that, instead of using an array, you should have used classes.